# Does a function() call in a while loop uses memory everytime the loop iterate?

Tags: c++

I'm new in here and I am currently learning how to program in C++.

So my question is: Does a function call inside a while loop cost memory every time the loop iterates?

Example:

```
int count = 0;

while (count < 10)
{
    function_call(); // Will this consume 10x more memory?
    ++count;
}
```

Comment: because your function has memory leaks. There is no garbage collector in C/C++.

Comment: @Jean There is no evidence of a memory leak in this code.

Comment: This question is unanswerable without a better description of "cost memory", an explanation of why the OP thinks the call should "cost memory", and an [MCVE].

Comment: It will only consume memory if the function allocates it and does not release it. The function may call itself - in that case the call will keep consuming stack space until all the recursive calls return, but there will be no memory accumulation when the next iteration of the loop begins,

Comment: There are two kinds of memory in C++.   One is called dynamic (i.e. 'in the heap' using new/delete), the other called automatic (on the 'stack', and scope limited).  Both have a finite supply, but typically 'automatic' is much smaller than 'dynamic'. What do you mean by 'costs'?

Answer (score 1):

No. †

You are calling your function 10 times, so whatever memory your function is using is used 10 times. But the function is called again only after it already ended execution, so whatever resources it used are already deallocated.

So in the end, it's using the same amount of memory, just holding it 10 times longer.

> †: This is assuming your function is not leaking memory.
>
> Any memory it allocates manually without freeing, will remain used. So if your function leaks N bytes, that loop will leak 10 times N bytes. But let's hope you're not leaking anything. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This question is ambiguous because there are 2 types memory for C++, dynamic and automatic (often called heap and stack), which have different characteristics.

```
int count = 0;
while (count < 10) {
   function_call(); // Will this consume 10x more memory?
   ++count;
}
```

---

1) will this consume 10x more automatic memory?

Answer - no.  Automatic memory is allocated upon scope entry, and released upon scope exit.  The loop repeated call to function_call() will 'start fresh' each invocation.

---

2) will this consume 10x more dynamic memory?

Answer - not really knowable with what you have provided.

NO - if function_call() does not use dynamic memory

NO - a) if function_call() 'uses' a finite amount of dynamic memory 
        acquired with new(), and 
        b) releases all that dynamic memory using delete prior to returning.

NO - a) if function_call 'uses' a finite amount of dynamic memory acquired 
           with new(), and 
        b) a different_function_call releases the memory appropriately.

```
    Research term for you: object lifetime.  Some dynamic memory
    needs to exists longer than the lifetime of the function_call.

    Several other answers mentioned 'memory leaking'.  I consider this a 
    coding error, and thus not relevant to your question.
```

Yes - a) if function_call 'uses' a finite amount of dynamic memory acquired
            with new(), and 
         b) no other code releases it, and 
         c) the process (containing function_call) does not terminate.

```
     On most OS's, terminating the process in which this code runs will 
     cause the release of all dynamic memory (and other resource) back
     to the OS's control, and no longer accessible to the terminated 
     process (or any other process in the form created).

     If it is possible that this process can run until dynamic memory is 
     exhausted, I think what happens next is UB (undefined behavior).
```